# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

Tags: javascript

This occured after I added the following lines in the `hook_init()` implementation done from a custom module.

```php
function myid_init() {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path("module", "myid") . "/photobooth-js-gh-pages/photobooth_min.js"); 
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path("module", "myid") . "/photobooth-js-gh-pages/website/js/script.js");
}
```

It needs jQuery 1.11.2 to work, but Drupal already uses jQuery.

I installed the *jQuery Update* module and found out that, in the configuration setting, the newer jQuery version I could select is 1.10, but that is not sufficient for jQuery plugin I want to use.

How can I use jQuery 1.11.2 in a Drupal site?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the drupal.org document on [using new versions of jQuery](https://www.drupal.org/node/1058168) for a few solutions. One good solution is the [JQuery Multi module](https://www.drupal.org/project/jqmulti) that lets you target multiple versions of jQuery via its `hook_jqmulti_libraries()` hook (its [README explains how](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/jqmulti/tree/README.txt?id=refs/heads;id2=7.x-1.x)).